# OpenStreetMap missing info

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I'm very new to OpenStreetMap.

I'm trying to find all fast food locations in an area. When I pull the data using `osmdata` in R there are a lot of rows with no information at all.

How are these classed as fast food locations?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(osmdata)

t = opq('Adur') %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = 'amenity', value = 'fast_food') %>%
  osmdata_sf()
View(head(t$osm_points))
```

The locations with OSM IDs `2439442254`, `2439828308`, and `2439828379` all have no information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with R, however the mentioned IDs are [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) belonging to [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) which in turn are tagged as fast food:

- [node 2439442254](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/2439442254) is part of [way 615644218](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/615644218)
- [node 2439828308](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/2439828308) is part of [way 235901529](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/235901529)
- [node 2439828379](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/2439828379) is also part of [way 235901529](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/235901529)

So I presume you are just looking at the wrong information in R.

Note that OSM has three basic [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements): nodes, ways and relations. Each of these elements can represent an individual fast food object, depending on how this information is stored in OSM.